# How can I add a blank row at the top of a Google Sheets spreadsheet automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a spreadsheet where we will add new clients as they are referred which will then populate an auditing spreadsheet.  We currently have the referrals sorted by month in different tabs, but this doesn't really work with what I want to do so I'm hoping to have all the new referrals listed in one sheet and sorted by date.  The problem is that as we get more and more new referrals the list will get very long and be a pain to view needing to scroll all the way to the bottom.

What I am hoping to do is add a blank row where new clients can be inputted and then sort descending by date.  It seems like this is something I would need to add a script for, but the ones I've tried don't seem to work like I want them to.  I also have very limited Google Sheets skills...  so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When do you want to add the blank row? When the sheet is opened? When some edit takes place?

Comment: I'm hoping to make it add the blank row when a new row has been filled.  I'm imaginging that when someone fills it out that it will bump it down a row and add a blank one to the top.

Comment: You need to define `a new row has been filled`. Is it a top row, bottom row, any row? What is the last column that needs to be filled in order to consider the row as "filled"?

Comment: It would be the very top row under the header row.  And then just the first two columns would need to be filled before adding a row above it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple solutions is do make a Macro. Go to -> Extra -> Macro's -> Record Macro. Then rightclick on row 1 and add a row above. Then go to the date column and sort how you want it. Hit save and you can give it a shortcut.

Now you can execute with your shortcut or Extra -> Marco's -> The created macro.

[Youtube tut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlOGJcfpfKU)

-Remco

Comment: Will this run automatically or would I have to run it after each new entry?

Comment: The macro is saved in your sheet. With thee apps script you can make a function onEdit() --> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

But with macro itself you can assign it to a keyboard shortcut, when you hit it it runs te macro..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a script that adds a row, and puts the date in the A column. 
The script is activated via a [button](http://googleappscripting.com/google-spreadsheet-button/) in my spreadsheet.

```html
function newLine() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.insertRowsAfter(2, 1); //assuming your first row is the header
      
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Europe/Amsterdam", "dd-MM-yyyy");
  var range2  = sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(today).setHorizontalAlignment("Left");
      }
```